# How to tell pdflatex to ignore one specific undefined control sequence?

Tags: pdftex, compilation-error

I have an undefined control sequence error which does not change anything regarding the output pdf and I cannot solve the problem ([see this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575771/undefined-control-sequence-setcolor-pdfcolorstack-push-currentcolor-a?noredirect=1#comment1451234_575771)). Pressing enter 3 times every single time I run pdflatex starts to become tedious.

What can I do (beside solving the original problem) to not have to press enter 3 times at every compilation?

Comment: Since you mentioned "error which does not change anything regarding the output pdf": Please do not ignore error messages. Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: You could try addding a `\providecommand\xxxx{}` just before the point where the undefined control sequence `\xxxx` is reported. I would _not_ recommend this as anything other than seeing the output as this problem should really need to be resolved.

Comment: you shouldn't ignore errors. I added an answer to your other question.

Comment: after any error the PDF is not intended to be usable. There is no reason to "ignore" an undefined command, simply define it. You could define it to do nothing but that is unlikely to be the correct fix.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer 's solution fixed the original problem.